# How to Load Picture to PictureBox in Windows mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How I can Load Picture to PictureBox in Windows mobile ?

there isn't somthing like "PictureBox1.Image.Load (......." ???

thank's

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the image object, then assign it to the PictureBox:

```
Image myImage = new Bitmap(...);
PixtureBox1.Image = myImage;
```

Comment: I'd modify that slightly to Dispose any existing image before assigning the new one to prevent an OOM, especially if you load often.

Comment: @ctacke: Good point. @Gold: Even though the GC will eventually handle it, Images require finalization which can cause them to stick around FAR longer than would otherwise be required. On a mobile device with little memory, you could run into an OOM before the GC has a chance to finish finalization.